# Upgrading one product but not the other when both products have the same upgrade code

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, uninstallation

I have two products installed. They have the same version number and upgrade code, but different product code. I would like to do a major upgrade on one of these products, but the upgrade exe that I created ends up removing both products, and installing new one.

That being said, how can I keep one product installed when the product has the same upgrade code with the another product that I would like to upgrade?

Comment: @Christopher Painter: hoping that you might be able to help me with this question...Thanks.

Comment: Is the [ProductLanguage property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/5d798825-c70b-4d5a-b88c-a9db40663f6a) also the same for both products? This scenario is not supported by the [Upgrade Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/f5fda405-8a09-495e-aa8c-b808a2f02b0f) if ProductLanguage is also the same. You can see [Using an UpgradeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/de62bb80-56a0-4652-9509-5d36ed171c69) in the MSDN docs for a description of supported scenario.

Comment: Done.  BTW, this is a real question.  You aren't the first to ask it either.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the ProductLanguage property is the same for both products..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Upgrade table first drives FindRelatedProducts.   FindRelatedProducts uses the information to perform MSI product searches.  If places the ProductCode of a found in the property specified by the ActionProperty column

Later, RemoveExistingProducts performs an uninstall of any ProductCodes found in any ActionProperty properties ( provided that msidbUpgradeAttributesOnlyDetect is not set ).

So the trick out of a sticky situation like this is to author an Upgrade row that will cause FindRelatedProducts to not find either product.  Then use a custom action to do your own searches and set the properties as needed ( one but not the other ).   Now RemoveExistingProducts will be able to perform the major upgrade.

As a side note: this is a work around and not a best practice.  Carefully consider your choice of UpgradeCodes, ProductCodes and ProductVersion properties to avoid this situation in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I know this is not really the best practice but it looks like I have no choice..Thank you again for your help. I appreciate it.